# Sets and set membership

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to figure what type of ML this falls into.

Let's say I have 10,000 users and 200 lists - Each user can belong to as many lists as they want. What type of ML system would evaluate the likelihood of a user belonging to list based on all the other users they share memberships with on all other lists.

(Hopefully that makes sense, I think this is a solved problem and I am just looking for a pointer to solution)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds almost like a recommendation problem. Let's see if replacing "user" with "item" and "list" with "user" in your original statement helps:

> Let's say I have 10,000 **items** and 200 **users** - Each **item** can belong to as many **users** as they want. What type of ML system would evaluate the likelihood of an **item** belonging to **user** based on all the other **items** they share memberships with on all other **users**.

In a recommender setting, you usually recommend an item to users by trying to predict the probability of a user consuming certain item. In your setting, you'll be trying to predict the probability of a list "consuming" certain user

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be to set up 200 KNN models, since the memberships are not exclusive. A dense neural network with member properties as input and 200 probability outputs should work too.